# How do I loop this code?

Tags: python, loops

How do I loop this code with a "do you want to run this again" question?

```
count = 1
total = 0

markslist = list()

while count <= 10:
    newmark = input("Input Mark Out Of 100 (" + str(count) + ") ")
    markslist.append(newmark)
    if newmark > 100: 
        import sys      
        sys.exit("Error Mark is greater than 100 re-run program")
    total = total + newmark 
    count = count + 1

average = (total / 10)

print "Average Mark = " + str(average)
```

Comment: Use `raw_input` or `input` to get string input from the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just wrap the entire code in a loop similar to this:

```
while True:
    again = input('Go? (y/n): ')
    if again != 'y':
        break

    # The entirety of the rest of your program would go here.
```